# Article usage in "AI technology" vs. "the English language"

Tags: articles, definite-article

Why some noun phrases require the definite article, some don't? They are quite similar in structure. Why do we say "the NYC area", "the English language", but "AI technology", "blockchain technology"? How are latter phrases different from former ones?

My hunch: technology here is a category? Is that the (only) reason?

Comment: As a native New Yorker, I can attest that no one says **the** JFK airport. It's just **JFK airport**, no article required.

Comment: @fjack You are right. I think in this case **airport** has been subsumed under the proper noun, which coming together becomes [JFK **A**irport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_F._Kennedy_International_Airport). I have seen it used with the article though, taking airport out of the proper noun, [example](https://traveltips.usatoday.com/motels-jfk-airport-57233.html). Of course, as you say, this is uncommon. Strangely I am under the impression there are airports whose names are of this pattern: the X airport. Anyways I need to think of better examples. Maybe **the NYC area** would work?

Answer (score 1):

The definite article is used to refer to a particular member of a group or class. (See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_(grammar)#Definite_article) for more on definite and indefinite articles.)

Some might disagree with where the borders are drawn, but there is exactly one NYC area. There are different varieties of English, but they are all part of one English language.

Usually when we talk about AI technology, we are not talking about a single invention. "AI technology" usually refers collectively to all of the inventions, mechanisms, and techniques related to artificial intelligence.

We would only use "the AI technology" if we *did* intend to talk about a specific type of AI technology in contrast to all of the other AI technologies, such when saying, "neural networks are the AI technology with the most success". (This is just an example; I am not trying to make this claim.)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, it's because *area* and *language* are countable while *technology* is uncountable.

The phrases *NYC area* and *English language* take "the" because the words *area* and *language* take "the". The phrases *AI technology* and *blockchain technology* don't usually take "the" because the word *technology* doesn't usually take "the".

Comment: I don't think it is an issue of countable/uncountable. Water is uncountable, but we can say "the water".

Comment: @Tashus We can say "the AI technology" and "the blockchain technology" too.

Comment: Right, so it isn't a matter of being countable.